# React native navigation class function in header

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I've got a problem with react native navigation and nested navigators.

Basically, the nested navigators (tab in a page) work pretty well. But when i add a button in the header with the _saveDetails function, it throw me an undefined function if i'm in the Players tab, and it works well when i'm on the Teams tab

Does anyone have an idea of what am i doing wrong? Thanks.

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
    return {
        headerRight: <Button title="Save" onPress={() => 
        params.handleSave()} />
    };
  };

  _saveDetails() {
    console.log('clicked save');
  }

 componentDidMount() {
   this.props.navigation.setParams({ handleSave: this._saveDetails });
 }

 render() {
    return (
        <View />
    );
  }
}

const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
  Players: { screen: HomeScreen},
  Teams: { screen: HomeScreen},
});

const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: MainScreenNavigator },
  Player: { screen: PlayerPage },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one and let me know if you fetch any other problem. Just convert your code according to below code.

static navigationOptions = {
  header: (navigation, header) => ({
    ...header,
    right: (
       navigation.navigate('Settings')}>
        Settings
      
    )
  })
}
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code become like this

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
   // const { params = {} } = navigation.state; //delete this
    return {
        headerRight: <Button title="Save" onPress={() => 
        navigation.state.params.handleSave()} />  // add navigation.state
    };
  };

.....
```